# markdown to uiview/nsview

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, markdown

I am trying to process a markdown string to display it in either a scrollable UIView or NSView on iOS and OSX in Objective-C/Cocoa. Is there a library available to implement this?

I have had a quick look on Google and there doesn't seem to be any obvious library to use.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is a library out there for Markdown, but if I had to add support for it in my app I'd directly translate it to HTML markup and show that in a webview. Provided it doesn't have to be editable, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on what Lvsti said, if you make use of one of the many Javascript Markdown interpreters through a Webview, you wouldn't even need to do the translation yourself; just make sure the script is loaded in your Webview and fire the appropriate Javascript selector to feed in the Markup.